# How to download all Google Search images results

Tags: google-image-search, bulk-download

Is there a way to automatically download all the images that Google shows up on Google Image Search?

I do not want to download the thumbnails and only the actual images in their actual sizes.

Comment: Fatkun Batch Download Image, a chrome plugin, downloads the big pictures of the search result (**not small icons** of the search page).  BTW, which sb blocked this post?

Answer (score 6):

A [quick search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google%20images%20downloader) for "Google images downloader" revealed two possible solutions:

1. [Google Images Downloader](http://download.cnet.com/Google-Image-Downloader/3000-2381_4-75439931.html) - (Desktop application)

   > Google Image Downloader (GiD) allows you to download images by entering a search term. It then hits the internet and downloads the full sized images from all of the sites Google images returns.

   Read more: Google Image Downloader - Free download and software reviews - CNET Download.com http://download.cnet.com/Google-Image-Downloader/3000-2381_4-75439931.html#ixzz2xAqVnmTR
2. [Image Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-downloader/cnpniohnfphhjihaiiggeabnkjhpaldj) - (Chrome extension)

   > See all images shown or linked on a web page and download them.

I guess if you want this kind of functionality in your own app these would be a good starting point.

Comment: Neither of these work (2017)

Comment: At least the Chrome extension is a brick.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Images Download](https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download) is a GitHub project which downloads images according to a Google Image search.

You can give it the *search term*, a *limit* on how many images you want to download and a *color filter* to narrow the results,..

Works perfectly!