# export saved Google images into Google photos

Tags: images, google-photos, online-storage, google-image-search, cloud

How do I **import** saved images from http://www.google.com/save/ into Google Photos **without** downloading them?

(From Linux.)

Similar to, but different from:

[How to download all Google Search images results](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/how-to-download-all-google-search-images-results)

example:

[image]

Comment: By clicking the upload button in Google Photos, navigate to your Downloads folder, selecting the images you have downloaded, and upload them?

Comment: but how do I get the images **into** google photos?  They're not **in** `google-photos`, but only in `google-image-search` as a "saved" image.

Comment: I don't see a button "to save each image to the cloud". Could it be that you have installed a browser extension? Maybe you could post a screenshot, showing the button you are talking about.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal LOL, there was a "save" button yesterday...maybe it was removed.  I can see images which I "saved" previously, but can't seem to add to "saved" images anymore...?  Or maybe it's just some images...?  sigh...google.  Try the link http://www.google.com/save/ to see whether you have any saved images.  How you add to that collection, don't know because it might have been removed in the past few days.

Comment: It looks like a bit of an experiment and isn't fully baked. I don't see that there is a way, especially since you can save links there as well as things from the Google _Save_ extension.

Comment: I'd suggest you use the "Feedback" tool to register your desire for this functionality. (I have.)